# Where is /etc/rc.local

Tags: 14.04, amazon-ec2

[image]

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html). I am working with an Ubuntu 14.04 instance on amazon EC2:

At the [end of the tut](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#make-uwsgi-startup-when-the-system-boots), it discusses:

"The last step is to make it all happen automatically at system startup time.
Edit /etc/rc.local and add ..."

I want to activate an existing virtualenv automatically at startup , for which I would manually use the command

```
workon myenv
```

when I inspect the `/etc` directory, I see the above screenshot. Where is `rc.local`?

**Edit 1** - I don't think its here:

[image]

Comment: As far as your need is concerned, you can add the command to `~/.profile` (for only yourself) or to `/etc/profile`(for all users) so that the command gets executed whenever you login via `ssh` or via console or graphically.

Comment: I looked in /etc. There is /etc/profile.d/ but no /etc/profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing only directories, `rc.local` is a file. Please use the command line or any other method (in the GUI program you are using) to view files too, you will get `rc.local` along with all other files.

Comment: please see edit 1

Comment: No, you are doing `ls -la` sitting in directory `rc0.d` so you getting the contents of `rc0.d`....`rc.local` file resides in `/etc`, you need enter the command `ls -l /etc`

Comment: Ok thank you, you are right. One more follow up question, so you think it would be better to put 'workon myenv' into the global /etc/profile file though, not rc.local?

Comment: @user61629: Yes, Ubuntu now uses upstart init system whereas `/etc/rc.local` is from the earlier sysV init system, though it is kept for backward compatibility....you can keep the command in `/etc/rc.local`, it would not be a problem but the better option would be `~/.profile` (for only you) or `/etc/profile` (for all users)..

Comment: thank you, and can I just put in a line like I would type at the command line, eg  'workon myenv' ?

Comment: @user61629: Yes, that will do..

Comment: @user61629: Happy to help :)